# Physical origin of coisotropic branes

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, mathematical-physics, topological-field-theory, branes

The paper ["Remarks on A-branes, Mirror Symmetry, and the Fukaya category"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0109098) develops the possibility of A-model open strings ending on a [coisotropic submanifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156519/coisotropic-submanifolds) equipped with a holomorphic transverse structure of the underlying target space.

On the other hand, it is possible to identify non-perturbative corrections to $A$ and $B$ models when topological string theory is embedded into physical string theory [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9309140) [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0403167) as coming from the full theory; examples are the $D(-1)$ and $D1$ instantons of the $B$ model as "descending" from its full IIB counterparts [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9309140),  the non-perturbative completion of the $A$ model counting $D6/D2/D0$ bound states [[3]](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0312022), A-model lagrangian branes "descending" from $M5$-branes wrapping lagriangian cycles etc. I was wondering to know if it is possible to have a similar interpretation for coisotropic branes.

Consider the critical $A$-model on a Calabi-Yau threefold with one space-filling coisotropic brane embedded into full string theory as in the section one of [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9309140).

***Question*: Does the coisotropic brane "descend" from a brane of the physical superstring?**